# Switch classes between siblings elements with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Let's say I have this code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
    <div class="child">
    <div class="child">
</div>
```

I want for a start to add automatically to the first child the class `active`. After that, I want for each X seconds to switch to the next child the `active` class. Is it possible to do this with Angular 2?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: @Brocco, TBH, I'm not quite familiar with Angular (1/2) So I tried to do it with jQuery but it's painful because every element here is appended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ck5dkTD4ACkFZawgHNoI?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

You can dynamically add a class and items to a list with a template like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
    class="child" [class.active]="activeIndex === i">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

With the supporting component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  activeIndex = 0;
  items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(_ => {
      this.activeIndex++;
      if (this.activeIndex >= this.items.length){
        this.activeIndex = 0;
      }
    }, 500)
  }
  addItem() {
    this.items.push('item ' + (this.items.length + 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your'e epic. Thank you!